# haproxy as a ipv4 to ipv6

Tags: haproxy, socat

i have a small linux server on the internet on which i run socat.

```
socat UDP4-LISTEN:1194,fork UDP6-SENDTO:[****:****:****:****:*** *:****:****:****]:1194
```

Which I installed as a service. So far it works well and without any problems. Incidentally, I need all of this because I only have an ipv6 that can be reached from the internet. There is also a service with tcp for port 80. Now I wanted to do it with haproxy. The idea was that I can redirect to other addresses based on the URL or the port. SSL would be nice too but first things first.
At first I wanted to redirect the udp port 1194.
So I added the following to the cfg:

```
listen vpn
        bind udp@:1194
        use-server wg_server if { hdr(host) -i abc.com }
        server wg_server ipv6@[####:####:####:####:####:####:####:####]:1194 check port 1194
```

But with cfg check (haproxy -c -f) I get the following message:
'bind' : dgram-type socket not acceptable in 'udp@:1194'

So without UDP:

```
listen vpn
        binding :1194
        use-server wg_server if { hdr(host) -i abc.com }
        server wg_server ipv6@[####:####:####:####:####:####:####:####]:1194
```

The cfg check is now ok but when I start haproxy I get the message:
proxy vpn has no server available!

A query via nmap reports that the port can be reached at the address. So something is wrong in the cfg. Anyone have a tip?

Kind regards
Orko

Answer (score 0):

Okay.  I probably should have checked that first.

haproxy doesn't support UDP. So I will stay with socat and simply redirect them
based on the port number.